# HDMI / Monitor Mic' Camera

Tags: sound, hdmi, monitor, microphone, camera

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Computer is an Acer Revo One, RL85.
- Monitor is a Philips 271P4Q

This computer came with Windows but had Ubuntu installed over Windows, as a new install.

The Acer has one HDMI port and one "headphone" port. Not a speaker port, but "headphones". There is no "Mic'" input. Although I have never plugged a headphone [I actually don't have one....] in I have my speakers running through this. I also suspect this is a "two way port", in and output, i.e., speakers and Microphone through the same headset port.

The HDMI is running the Monitor.
Even with the speakers plugged in / working, I can switch to Monitor / HDMI sound output, which works fine.

I can not get either the camera nor microphone working on the Philips monitor.

In "settings" there is only one input : Analogue Input, Built in Audio.
I have no option for "HDMI Input", or similar.

In short, can I / how do I make the HDMI Microphone / camera work, or, is this a hardware limitation because I am running on a "mini pc" and the hardware won't do it? Will I need to buy a headset / mic' and separate camera?

As an aside, the Acer runs Ubuntu perfectly, all my other peripherals work and I have no issues. I suspect however this is a limitation of the number of ports and therefore how the sound card is managing the input feeds.

Ideas from anybody?

Comment: The other audio devices including HDMI audio are irrelevant here and your description of the "headphone" port is just noise (BTW, yes, probably a combo plug like the ones typically found in tablets/phones). The "webcam+mic" is a independent device from the monitor itself and it uses a USB cable that oddly you didn't mention and should be plug'n'play like any other cheap generic webcam in the market today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monitor [Philips 271P4Q](http://www.p4c.philips.com/cgi-bin/cpindex.pl?scy=TH&slg=EN&ctn=271P4QPJKEB/00) may look like as a "2-in-1" device but it's actually a case of two independent devices bundled in the same enclosure.

The monitor itself is standard and uses a typical HDMI connection. The webcam is also generic and requires an additional USB cable.

According to the [user manual](http://download.p4c.philips.com/files/2/271p4qpjkeb_00/271p4qpjkeb_00_dfu_aen.pdf), the system requirements for the webcam are:

> Operating system : Microsoft Windows 7, 
>   Microsoft Windows Vista,  Microsoft Windows 
>   XP (SP2), and **any other OS whichever 
>   support UVC/UAC (USB Video Class 
>   compliant / Audio Class compliant) under 
>   USB 2.0 standard** (my bold)

Ubuntu is such a case for many years now and it should be plug'n'play (the same for Windows 10).

In order to use the webcam and microphone you need to connect the additional USB cable. In the back of the monitor you'll find a USB type B connector, similar to the one used by USB2.0 peripherals:

[image: USB type B]

Once properly connected the webcam should be automatically detected by Ubuntu (or Windows 10) and ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a few hours dedicated to this and I have found the answer: it won't work.

The monitor I have has neither Linux nor Windows 10 Drivers. It seems that Philips have not updated drivers for W10 for lots of their monitors when they decided to go all out for the health care and personal health markets.

So, regardless of what I do with Ubuntu there is nothing that will get the Mic' or Camera working. So, I will be looking for a stand alone web cam and Mic'.

C'est le vie.

Comment: Dumb question: Have you connected the additional USB cable? Assuming you did then it should work (except in the case of hardware failure) because in its manual Philips, regarding supported OSes,  stated *(...) any other OS whichever support UVC/UAC (USB Video Class compliant / Audio Class compliant) under USB 2.0 standard*. Ubuntu is such a case for many years now and it should be plug'n'play (the same for Windows 10).

Comment: Is there a dumb question ?
No, I had not. Why ? 
1: I did not know I needed to.
2: becuase of how I have the monitor [physically] set up, I had totally forgotten there were any ports. It turns out there are four USBs and one "printer" port on the side.

So, now I have shoved a cable in I have both a working Mic' and camera.

Thanks Michael, that has helped a lot.